# Benefits of Scaling vs Media Queries for Responsive Web Design

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm hoping to understand the benefits of Scaling a design instead of using Media Queries for responsive web design.

I recently made a website where I needed to ensure that the design remained the same regardless of the user zooming in and out of the design. The solution I came with was rather simple:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">    
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <div id="element"></div>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
html {
    font-size:1.1vw;
}

#container {
    width:50vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size:3.125rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}

#element {
    width:25rem;
    height:15.63rem;
    background:green;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

In the above example, [which you can see on codepen too](https://codepen.io/uziiuzair/pen/XWXgJoB), the code allows you to zoom in and out of the browser and resize the browser while maintaining an emulated responsive design. I saw emulated since I believe that media queries would still be needed to adjust the design for Tablets and definitely phones. ([By the way, you can compare the above codepen example with one that does not use REM here](https://codepen.io/uziiuzair/pen/QWygbwO))

Now with this example, I wanted to understand what are some possible upsides and downsides (apart from possible browser compatibility issues) of using a "Scaling" method in comparison to the traditional "Media Query" method of doing responsive design? Should I consider this method for all my future website projects?

---

Note: as someone mentioned in the comments that this would be an issue on smaller screens (Mobile is an example) the question above mentions that Mobile and Tablets may still need media queries to adjust the design for smaller screens. In that regard, what would your thoughts be for Desktop and Laptops. Using Scaling as an alternative to coding breaking points for Desktop and Laptop screens?

Comment: On a small screen your *primary heading* is about the smallest font size that I could comfortably read.

Comment: If people zoom in, its because they *need the content to be bigger*. This completely defeats that.

Comment: @Quentin that's understandable. However, I did mention that media queries might still be needed for Tablet and Mobile. In that regard, I recommend keeping the discussion to just Desktop and Laptop. Would scaling be a viable option for say Desktop and Laptop instead of coding breakpoints?